# Is there way to be absolutely sure that access came from QR code scan?

Tags: qr-code

I need some help with `QR codes`

I've being reading about it but I couldn't find a straight answer from the question:

> Is it possible to make sure that access came from a `QR` scan?

I have created a `QR` and I need to make sure that the access came from it... From where I stand, I learned that I can simply scan a `QR code`, save the `url` and access it from plain text.

I've created a url with `parameters` ej: `example.com/?qr=true` but I can copy it and access with the parameter, thus it don't solve my problem...

Is there a way to add `meta-data` into my `qr code`?
I've check and I don't get a ref in the header, can I manually add it?

Thanks is advance!

PS: I'm using `qrcode` Python library to generate my `qr-code`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, apart from using a url query parameter, you're out of luck.

Comment: As all such requests are pure HTTP requests that can originate from anywhere: no

Comment: I know that Denso-Wave has [a solution](https://www.denso-wave.com/en/system/qr/product/sqrc.html) to store "other data", where you can store your parameters. This requires a fairly deep study into inner workings of QR codes, and there are probably simpler ways to do what you need, such as server-side auth, timecodes etc. Just wanted to mention it.

Comment: @MyICQ as far as I see, that won't work for public facing codes that should be accessible by everyone without special devices or applications. Also, the "inner workings" of QR codes are pretty simple